# IBKR API Display Groups

Tags: python

I am having an issue with the logic of linking IBKR API Display Group to my code. I am trying to get Display Group 1 to connect from IBKR TWS to my Jupyter notebook.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import threading
import numpy as np

class MyWrapper(EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.df=None
        
    def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):
        print("Setting nextValidOrderId: %d", orderId)
        self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
        self.start()

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        self.data.append(vars(bar));
        
    def historicalDataUpdate(self, reqId, bar):
        line = vars(bar)
        self.df.loc[pd.to_datetime(line.pop('date'))] = line
        
    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId: int, start: str, end: str):
        print("HistoricalDataEnd. ReqId:", reqId, "from", {start}, "to", {end})
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.data)
        self.df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['date'])
        self.df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
        
    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , errorString)

    def start(self):
        queryTime = ""
        
        contract = Contract()
        contract.secType = "STK" 
        contract.symbol = ""
        contract.currency = "USD"
        contract.exchange = "SMART"
        

        app.reqHistoricalData(1, contract, queryTime, "5 Y", "1 day", "MIDPOINT", 0, 1, True, [])

wrap = MyWrapper()        
app = EClient(wrap)
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, clientId=123)


threading.Thread(target = app.run).start()

import time
time.sleep(5)
```

From the IBKR documentation it provides
https://ibkrcampus.com/ibkr-api-page/twsapi-doc/#query-display-groups
https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/display_groups.html

```
self.queryDisplayGroups(requestId)
```

```
def displayGroupList(self, reqId: int, groups: str):
  print("DisplayGroupList. ReqId:", reqId, "Groups", groups)
```

```
self.subscribeToGroupEvents(19002, 1)
```

```
def displayGroupUpdated(self, reqId: int, contractInfo: str):
  print("DisplayGroupUpdated. ReqId:", reqId, "ContractInfo:", contractInfo)
```